# How to get date of last week's X day for any month from provided date or from GetDate() for current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, week-number, weekday

Reverse question is -
How to determine if the date is in last week of month?

For example, using GetDate() how would I know that today's date or given date is in last week of the month. 
As week number in MSSQL can be 4 or 5.

***Suppose I want to get date of last Saturday of every month.*** 
But in SQL week number 5 (which is last week of Dec 2013) for Dec 2013 don't have Friday. Last week of December ends with Tue on 31st.
So, I need to skip Dec and go further for January 2014 but there also last week ends on Friday 31st.
So, keep moving....

**So, how to get date of last week's X day from given date or today's date?**

Thanks.

Comment: So, you are wanting to get 27th Dec as the last Friday in Dec 2013?

Comment: I don't find your narrative very clear - can you give some example input dates and the date that the solution needs to compute from those example inputs?

Comment: @Raj NO. In this case I need to ignore Dec and Jan to April months as their last week don't have Saturday. So, directly reach at May as May's last week has Saturday.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Given date is GetDate() or startdate from which we need to reach at some point. Suppose StartDate is 1 Dec 2013. We need to reach at such date where the date will be in importantly last week of month and also it is Saturday. But as Dec->April no month have Friday in last week. So, finally we get May where 31 May 2013 is Saturday. Hope it might be clear some what. Don't worry about start date it can be anything. We need to just go further to meed last week day condition. Thanks.

Comment: So, is a better way to put it that, from a particular start date, you need to find the earliest date which is the 5th Friday of its respective month?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below. It is based on week starting on Monday and ending on Sunday:

```
declare @date as date = '20131230' -- this is the date you check

declare @lastdayofmonth as date = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@date)+1,0))
declare @lastweekstart as date = dateadd(d, -datepart(dw, @lastdayofmonth)+2, @lastdayofmonth)
if datepart(m, @lastdayofmonth) <> datepart(m, @lastweekstart)
    set @lastweekstart = dateadd(d, -7, @lastweekstart)

if @date >= @lastweekstart and @date <= @lastdayofmonth
    print 'Within last week'
else
    print 'Not within last week'
```